# Erro conexao MySQL Web

Tags: java, mysql, hospedagem

Olá, estou tentando conectar uma classe java com um BD MySQL do host db4free.net mas está retornando o erro abaixo:

```
SQLException: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

Alguém sabe o que pode ser ?

Minha classe de conexao:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConexaoMySQL {

private String user = "user";
private String pass = "pass";
private String dbClass = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private String dbDriver = "jdbc:mysql://db4free.net:3307/corrente";
private Connection conn = null;

public boolean connect() {
    boolean done = false;
    //load driver
    try {
        Class.forName(dbClass).newInstance();
        System.out.println("driver loaded"); // THIS IS BEING RETURNED
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
    // Connection
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbDriver, user, pass);
        System.out.println("connected"); // THIS IS NOT BEING RETURNED
        done = true;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex);
    }
    return done;
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ConexaoMySQL().connect();
    }

}
```

Comment: Se você declarar o método `connect()` como estático? `public static  boolean connect() {...`

Comment: É bem provável que seja a versão do seu driver MySql, incompatível com a versão do seu Java. Tenta atualizar a versão (se estiver usando o Maven: procura no MVN repo por mysql-connector-java).

Comment: Não funcionou nem alterar o método connect() para statico, nem mysql connector atualizado, segue mesmo erro, no mwu mysql localhost conecta normal....vou seguir pesquisando, obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score -1):

Baixe esse conector: https://cdn.mysql.com//Downloads/Connector-J/mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.zip

Descompacte ele em alguma pasta e importe o mysql-connector-java-5.1.47-bin.jar na biblioteca do seu projeto e use os mesmo comandos para conectar com o DB.